# $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} {(\frac{f(x)}{x})} = 2$. Prove that the series $a_n=f(1)+f(\frac{1}{2})+...+(\frac{1}{n})$ is diverging to infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have a feeling this has something to do with the harmonic series. I feel like I need to find a step that does something like $f(x)=2x$ but I think this is not allowed.

Comment: This smells like L'Hopital could be useful...

Comment: Isn't  L'Hopital applied only for $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$?

Comment: Yes but $x\to 0$ woud mean $x\to 0$ and also $f(x)\to0$ (since, if $f(x)\to\ c\neq 0$, then $\frac{f(x)}{x}\to \infty\neq 2$)

Comment: Yeah but isn't $f(x)$ going to $0$? If it's going to anything else than the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: That was my point. $f(x)$ goes to $0$ when $x\to 0$. With L'Hopital we then get $f'(x)\to 2$ when $x\to 0$

Comment: I posted the comment before seeing yours. We're on the same page here.

Comment: l'Hospital's rule  can hardly be used if we don't know whether $\;f\;$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0 s.t. \forall x,  |x|<\delta \implies |\frac{f(x)}{x}-2|<\epsilon$

Set $x = \frac{1}{n}$ and we deal with positive n's, then we have $\forall n, n>\frac{1}{\delta} \implies 2-\epsilon < \frac{f(\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}<2+\epsilon$

Choosing $\epsilon<2$, we obtain $f(\frac{1}{n}) > 0$

Now you can use comparison rule.

Compare $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n f(\frac{1}{k})$  with $b_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k}$

We know $b_n$ is divergent.

$lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{f(\frac{1}{k})}{\frac{1}{k}}$ = $lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 2$

By the rule $a_n$ is divergent.

Comment: Why is $a_n$ divergant?

Comment: Rule says unless the limit equals to 0, if $b_n$ is divergent, then $a_n$ is divergent.

Comment: Excuse, but I think this answer is wrong, or at least incomplete. The limit-comparison test is appliable to positive series, and we don't know this about $\;f\;$ , so this cannot be accepted. Besides, this test says that if the limit is positive, one series is convergent iff the other one is.

Comment: @Joanpemo +1 for f to be positive (I added to the proof) but -1 for  $(p \iff q) $ = $(\lnot p \iff \lnot q)$

Comment: @cbahadir Thank you, yet I don't understand your last point: you wrote in the comment that "the rule says ... if $\;b_n \;$ is divergent then $\;a_n\;$ is is divergent", but as I wrote it must be an iff argument: one converges (or diverges, of course) iff the other one converges (diverges). In fact, if the limit is zero then if the one in the numerator diverges then so does the one in the numerator (or if the den. converges then so does the numerator).

Comment: @Joanpemo The $(p \iff q)$ statement reduces to $(\lnot q \implies \lnot p)$ in our problem.

Comment: @cbahadir I know that, thank you. Yet you said the rule is *only* one sided in your first comment above. I only made the point that the rule actually states the iff .

Answer (score 3):

Given any $\varepsilon>0$, since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=2$ we can choose $N$ large enough so that $\forall x<\frac{1}{N}$:$-\varepsilon<\frac{f(x)}{x}-2<\varepsilon$ $$\rightarrow\sum_{n=N}^{N+k}f(\frac{1}{n})>(2-\varepsilon)\sum_{n=N}^{N+k}\frac{1}{n}$$

for all $k>0$.

Now you just need to make $k$ large enough that the LHS go to infinity.

Comment: Very nice proof. +1

Answer (score 2):

If
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}
=2
$,
then,
for some
$c > 0$,
$0 < x < c
\implies
\frac{f(x)}{x}
> 1
$
or
$f(x) > x$
or
$f(1/n)
> 1/n
$
for $n > 1/c
$.

Therefore,
if
$n > \frac{2}{c}
$,
$\sum_{k=1}^n f(1/k)
=\sum_{k \le 1/c} f(1/k)+\sum_{k>1/c}^{k \le n} f(1/k)
\gt\sum_{k>1/c}^{k \le n} 1/k
\gt \ln(n)-\ln(1/c)
\to \infty
$
as
$n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. You may want to be more specific in the proof below (ie, apply more accurately the definition of the limit). My 2 cents: since the limit of $f(x)/x$ is 2 then, for exits $n_0$ such that for all $n > n_0$ we have $f(x)/x > 1, x = 1/n $ (in other words, when the argument $x$ get close to $0$ then $f(x)/x$ is in a vicinity of the limit $2$, and is bigger than $1$. Now: $a_n = a_{n0} + f(\frac{1}{n_0+1}) +  f(\frac{1}{n_0+2}) +\dots$ satisfies $a_n >= a_{n0} + \frac{1}{n_0+1}+\frac{1}{n_0+2}+\dots$, which is unbound (related to the harmonic series you mention). I hope this is somewhat clear...